# react-stomp-hooks disconnect from websocket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, stomp

I have a problem with react-stomp-hooks. I have a token that expires in an hour and after it expires it starts ddosing my server and in this time the main connection in stomp provider tries to reconnect. And i need to disconnect user from websocket to prevent those ddosing requests. Theres my provider:

```
 <StompSessionProvider
        url={`${BASE_URL()}/users/v1/open/notifications-websocket`}
        // connectHeaders={{Authorization: getAuthorizationHeader()}}
        reconnectDelay={1}
        onStompError={(evt) => {
           //todo disconnect
        }}
        debug={STOMP => console.log({STOMP})}
        onConnect={() => console.log({STOMP_CONNECT: "TCP connection successfully established"})}
    >
```

Tried to use stomp client with useStompClient but it didnt helped